# Реализация Admob в приложении на libgdx

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, admob, google-play-services

В одном из гайдов по реалзации рекламы EdMob в приложениях на LibGdx написано, что нужно в bild.gradle (android module) добавить такие строки

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.4'
}
```

после их добавления и синхронизации проекта возникает ошибка (скрин ниже)

[image]

Как добавить сервисы google play без ошибок?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что для работы библиотеки необходима как минимум 14 версия API Android. Об этом сказано в инструкции ["как начать"](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start). Ещё в этой инструкции рекомендуется использовать последнюю версию библиотеки AdMob. Сейчас это версия:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        // или google() для Android Studio 3.x
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Ответ станет гораздо понятнее для широкой аудитории, если вы добавите в него пояснения, что, куда и зачем нужно в этом фрагменте конфигурации.